# How do you connect ADB to a Nook on a Mac?

Tags: android, adb

`adb devices` returns nothing when I connect my Mac to the Nook.

Does it need a special driver or some configuration setting?

Answer (score 1):

To get a NOOK into developer mode, you have to join the NOOK Developer program at http://nookdeveloper.com and then upgrade to NOOK App Developer. The Developer Mode tool will create a provision.cmd file for you to download to your NOOK and then it will be fully accessible to adb, ddms, etc.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Nook is in Debugging mode.